# How to implement a list in a model without ManyToManyField in django rest framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Good afternoon, I'm making an API for mobile application similar to ToDo, and I ran into the problem of what I can't implement for tasks.
There is a basic model

```
class Task(models.Model):
    NameTask = models.TextField(null=True)
    DescriptionTask = models.TextField(null=True)
    SubTasks = models.ManyToManyField(SubTasks)
    DateTask = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    UserToken = models.TextField(default="")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['NameTask']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.NameTask[0:50]
```

as well as auxiliary

```
class SubTasks(models.Model):
    NameSubTasks = models.TextField(null=True)
    DescriptionSubTasks = models.TextField(null=True)
```

Вut the problem is that in order to shove an auxiliary model into the main one, an instance of the auxiliary must already exist, such restrictions are imposed by ManyToManyField.
So that's how best to implement a list of subtasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should connect SubTasks to Task

```
class Task(models.Model):
    NameTask = models.TextField(null=True)
    DescriptionTask = models.TextField(null=True)
    DateTask = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    UserToken = models.TextField(default="")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['NameTask']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.NameTask[0:50]
]
class SubTasks(models.Model):
    NameSubTasks = models.TextField(null=True)
    DescriptionSubTasks = models.TextField(null=True)
    task=models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='subtasks')
```

look at it like group and members. you should connect members to group and not put members in Group model.